# Suggestions on ether wallets for easy use?

Tags: transactions, wallets, ether

Does anyone have any suggestions on ether wallets that provide fast (no syncing required) interface like MyEtherWallet and also easy to navigate for making transactions (without the need to work out how much Gas the user needs to spend)?

Comment: This question will probably be closed [as a duplicate](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!